# quyering a json file in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have a json file in Azure Storage account which I need to query using Synapse SQL serverless pool. On running the below query I get the first 10 result of my file. I have copied the sample output to understand the content and schema. I need to write a query such that i get those enteries where **logs** do not have
*system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker* *and system:serviceaccounts:internal-services* and **time** should be between 2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z\ and 2022-05-23T17:45:13.0000000Z\

Can someone help me in writing a Query here. The Query which I run and get first 10 result are here:

```
select top 10 *
from openrowset(
        bulk 'https://azdevogs.blob.core.windows.net/insights-logs-kube-audit/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/533AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-TEST/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-TEST/y=2022/m=05/d=23/h=13/m=00/PT1H.json',
        format = 'csv',
        fieldterminator ='0x0b',
        fieldquote = '0x0b'
    ) with (doc nvarchar(max)) as rows
go
```

Result:

```
[{"data":[["{ \"operationName\": \"Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read\", \"category\": \"kube-audit\", \"ccpNamespace\": \"5f40f\", \"resourceId\": \"/SUBSCRIPTIONS/531C3AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV\", \"properties\": {\"log\":\"{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"Event\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"audit.k8s.io/v1\\\",\\\"level\\\":\\\"Metadata\\\",\\\"auditID\\\":\\\"b7bca3\\\",\\\"stage\\\":\\\"ResponseComplete\\\",\\\"requestURI\\\":\\\"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/velero/httpchaos?limit=500\\\",\\\"verb\\\":\\\"list\\\",\\\"user\\\":{\\\"username\\\":\\\"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"3feceb35e\\\",\\\"groups\\\":[\\\"system:serviceaccounts\\\",\\\"system:serviceaccounts:internal-services\\\",\\\"system:authenticated\\\"]},\\\"sourceIPs\\\":[\\\"35.205.140.108\\\"],\\\"userAgent\\\":\\\"kubectl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62876fc\\\",\\\"objectRef\\\":{\\\"resource\\\":\\\"httpchaos\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"velero\\\",\\\"apiGroup\\\":\\\"chaos-mesh.org\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1alpha1\\\"},\\\"responseStatus\\\":{\\\"metadata\\\":{},\\\"code\\\":200},\\\"requestReceivedTimestamp\\\":\\\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.140759Z\\\",\\\"stageTimestamp\\\":\\\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.146101Z\\\",\\\"annotations\\\":{\\\"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token\\\":\\\"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker\\\",\\\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\\\":\\\"allow\\\",\\\"authorization.k8s.io/reason\\\":\\\"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\\\\\\"spinnaker-cluster-admin\\\\\\\" of ClusterRole \\\\\\\"cluster-admin\\\\\\\" to ServiceAccount \\\\\\\"spinnaker/internal-services\\\\\\\"\\\"}}\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"pod\":\"kube-apiserver-76d-q68\"}, \"time\": \"2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z\", \"Cloud\": \"AzureCloud\", \"Environment\": \"prod\", \"UnderlayClass\": \"hcp-underlay\", \"UnderlayName\": \"hcp-underlay-westeurope-cx-624\"}"],["{ \"operationName\": \"Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read\", \"category\": \"kube-audit\", \"ccpNamespace\": \"5ff040f\", \"resourceId\": \"/SUBSCRIPTIONS/531B20C3AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV\", \"properties\": {\"log\":\"{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"Event\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"audit.k8s.io/v1\\\",\\\"level\\\":\\\"Metadata\\\",\\\"auditID\\\":\\\"f2b766d\\\",\\\"stage\\\":\\\"ResponseComplete\\\",\\\"requestURI\\\":\\\"/apis/chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1/namespaces/velero/iochaos?limit=500\\\",\\\"verb\\\":\\\"list\\\",\\\"user\\\":{\\\"username\\\":\\\"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"3fec72feb35e\\\",\\\"groups\\\":[\\\"system:serviceaccounts\\\",\\\"system:serviceaccounts:internal-services\\\",\\\"system:authenticated\\\"]},\\\"sourceIPs\\\":[\\\"35.205.140.108\\\"],\\\"userAgent\\\":\\\"kubectl/v1.18.10 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/62876fc\\\",\\\"objectRef\\\":{\\\"resource\\\":\\\"iochaos\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"velero\\\",\\\"apiGroup\\\":\\\"chaos-mesh.org\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1alpha1\\\"},\\\"responseStatus\\\":{\\\"metadata\\\":{},\\\"code\\\":200},\\\"requestReceivedTimestamp\\\":\\\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.156899Z\\\",\\\"stageTimestamp\\\":\\\"2022-05-23T13:45:13.162219Z\\\",\\\"annotations\\\":{\\\"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token\\\":\\\"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker\\\",\\\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\\\":\\\"allow\\\",\\\"authorization.k8s.io/reason\\\":\\\"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\\\\\\"spinnaker-cluster-admin\\\\\\\" of ClusterRole \\\\\\\"cluster-admin\\\\\\\" to ServiceAccount \\\\\\\"spinnaker/internal-services\\\\\\\"\\\"}}\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"pod\":\"kube-apiserver-768d-q68\"}, \"time\": \"2022-05-23T13:45:13.0000000Z\", \"Cloud\": \"AzureCloud\", \"Environment\": \"prod\", \"UnderlayClass\": \"hcp-underlay\", \"UnderlayName\": \"hcp-underlay-westeurope-cx-624\"}"],,"schema":[{"columnName":"doc","ordinal":0,"dataTypeName":"nvarchar"}]]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `openjson` function to parse your json array into a table.  This way you can extract data from json array to relational format.

The json sample you provided is not a valid json. Make sure that the actual data you are querying is valid json, otherwise you get a `JSON text is not properly formatted` -error.

You data looks like it is coming from AKS diagnostics logs/audit logs, but the json format is not the original log format. Are you on purpose transforming this to another structure? For the original Azure diagnostics logs structure for AKS audit logs the following example SQL query would result into a relation with columns username and time, and you would be able to filter based on these:

```
SELECT logs.time, logitem.username
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://....core.windows.net/.../PT1H.json',
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
    FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b'
)
WITH (
    jsonContent varchar(MAX)
) AS [result] cross apply openjson (jsonContent, '$') 
   with ( 
           time nvarchar(max) '$.time',
           logjson nvarchar(max) '$.properties.log'
           )  logs cross apply openjson (logs.logjson, '$') 
   with ( 
           username nvarchar(max) '$.user.username'
           )  logitem
```

For this query you can add simple time and username filter in where-clause like with normal sql.

You can find more info for the openjson syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Format of JSON file is very important. I'll do by standard JSON. First, check the rows.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM OPENROWSET(
            BULK'https://azdevogs.blob.core.windows.net/insights-logs-kube-audit/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/533AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-TEST/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-TEST/y=2022/m=05/d=23/h=13/m=00/PT1H.json',
            FORMAT='CSV',
            PARSER_VERSION='1.0',
            FIELDTERMINATOR='0x0b',
            FIELDQUOTE='0x0b',
            ROWTERMINATOR='0x0b'
        ) 
    WITH (
            jsonDoc NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) AS [result]
    
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsonDoc)
```

Now, separate row by columns. I wrote column1,column2 that I don't know the column name. Just after write file's columns, add data type of column. If there is one more array, choose data type as nvarchar(max) then do "CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsonDoc)
WITH (columns in array)" again.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK'https://azdevogs.blob.core.windows.net/insights-logs-kube-audit/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/533AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-TEST/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-TEST/y=2022/m=05/d=23/h=13/m=00/PT1H.json',
        FORMAT='CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION='1.0',
        FIELDTERMINATOR='0x0b',
        FIELDQUOTE='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR='0x0b'
    ) 
WITH (
        jsonDoc NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS [result]

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsonDoc)
WITH (
        column1 dataytpe1,
        column2 datetype2,
        ...
)
```